# jquery clone clear values after cloning

Tags: jquery

I am cloning a section but not able to clear the values with the below code 3rd line. Am I doing wrong ?

```
var divID = "CCPanel" + uniqueId;


 $('#' + divID).find('input,select').each(function () {    
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + uniqueId);    
    $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + uniqueId);
    $(this).attr('value', '');

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/17/)

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: SELECT doesn't have an attribute value, if it is your issue. If not, improve your question

Comment: I am working on adding jsfiddle though i have accepted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this might work

```
$(this).val('');
```

worked in this page with this code:

```
$('div').find('input,select').each(function () {    
$(this).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what exactly your trying to achieve, but to clear value you can use the below for input.

```
$(this).val('');
```

for select you can try out

```
$(this).prop('selectedIndex',-1);
```

Comment: I like your answer aswell ...added jsfiddle